# I am trying to use lists to choose a character in python IDLE. However, it either loops the input or freezes the window so I have to start again

Tags: python

This is for an assignment. I need to compare if user input is on a list. For this I thought I would make a character choosing code that would be used in a later project. This code loops the input until you click cancel and then it freezes the window. My previous two codes simply froze the window immediately.

```
def main():
    names = ["x", "y", "z"]
    while(c == 0):
        newName = input("What character would you like?")
            for n in range(0, len(names):
                if(newName == names):
                    print("You have chosen " + str(newName) + ".")
                    c = 1
                else:
                    c = 0

main()
```

Comment: To check newName is in list names, you only need `if newName in names:`.  If you want to loop (much less efficient) you should have `for n in names: if newName == n: ...`

Comment: The code posted will quit with NameError.  newName will never equal the list names.  Please post code that runs.  The editor and IDE you use to write and run code is generally not relevant.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example will help you ask better questions and write better code.

Answer (score 0):

so, this may be an error you made while writing the question, but your statement checking whether the name written is in the list is checking to see if newName=["x","y","z"], its checking for the entire list, not the specific items in the list. so a possible fix would be:

```
c=True
def main():
    global c
    names = ["x", "y", "z"]
    while c:
        newName = input("What character would you like? ")
        for n in range(0, (len(names)-1)):
            if(newName == names[n]):
                print("You have chosen " + str(newName) + ".")
                c = False
            else:
                c = True
main()
```

now when you run the program, in line 8 the names[n] checks the "n"th item in the list so say n=0 the statement would check the first item in the list because of the way python lists work. for some reason, and I cant quite figure out why, the program runs twice when it should only run once. Also, use Boolean variables, they're easier to use when you only have two options e.g. 1 and 0. The (len(names)-1) in line 7 is so that you don't get an error message saying that the list doesn't have that many items because in python lists 0 is the first item in the list

Comment: I think you made a small mistake in `range(0, (len(names)-1))` which misses the last item of the list. It should be `range(0, len(names))` or more simply `range(len(names))`. To verify this for yourself, try running a simple `print(list(range(0, 10)))`